# Vertx - wait till data available in redis

Tags: java, asynchronous, redis, vert.x

I am new to Vertx and was exploring request-reply using event bus.

I want to implement below flow

1. User requests for a data
2. controller sends a message on event bus to a redis-processor verticle
3. redis-processor will wait for n seconds till value is available in redis (there will be a background process which will keep on refreshing cache, hence the wait)
4. redis-processor will send reply back to controller
5. controller responds to user

In short I want to do something like this:

[image]

Now I want to implement this in Vertx since vertx can run asynchronously. Using event bus I can isolate controller from processor. So controller can accept multiple user request and stay responsive under load.
(I hope I am right with this!)

I have implemented this in very crude fashion in java-vertx. Stuck in below part.

```
//receive request from controller
vertx.eventBus().consumer(REQUEST_PROCESSOR, evtHandler -> {
    String txnId = evtHandler.body().toString();
    LOGGER.info("Received message:: {}", txnId);

    this.redisAPI.get(txnId, result -> {          // <=====
        String value = result.result().toString();
        LOGGER.info("Value in redis : {}", value);
        evtHandler.reply(value); // reply to controller
    });
});
```

pls see line denoted by arrow. How can I wait for x seconds without blocking event loop?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats actually very simple, you need a timer. Please see [docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_one_shot_timers) for details but you will need more or less something like this:

```
vertx.setTimer(1000, id -> {
    this.redisAPI.get(txnId, result -> {          
        String value = result.result().toString();
        LOGGER.info("Value in redis : {}", value);
        evtHandler.reply(value); // reply to controller
    });
});
```

You might want to store the timer IDs somewhere so that you can cancel them or that at least you know something is running when a shutdown request comes in for your verticle to delay it. But this all depends on your needs.

Comment: Yes thanks for ur answer. I have implemented actually by using `setPeriodic`. In that I poll with duration of some millis. Once I get data i cancel timer and return response. 
I have one another issue in that, is how to keep an upper limit on poll. how to exit once n seconds have passed?

Comment: periodic would also work. regarding cancelling, you can come up with any self designed mechanism. Vertx provides you only the basic tools. You can for example set a timer after your periodic (having its ID) that cancels the periodic when it triggers (or just ignores if it can not be canceled meaning done already).

Answer (score 0):

As @mohamnag said, you could use a [Vertx timer](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_one_shot_timers)

[here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/vert.x/timers.html) is another example on how to user timer.

Note that the timer value is in `ms`.

As an improvement to the, I will recommend checking that the callback has succeeded before attempting to get the value from redisAPI. This is done using the [`succeeded() method`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/AsyncResult.html).
In an asynchronous environment getting that result could fail due to several issues (network errors etc)

```
 vertx.setTimer(n * 1000, id -> {
    this.redisAPI.get(txnId, result -> {
      if(result.succeeded()){  // the callback succeeded to get a value from redis
        String value = result.result().toString();
        LOGGER.info("Value in redis : {}", value);
        evtHandler.reply(value); // reply to controller
      } else {
        LOGGER.error("Value could not be gotten from redis : {}", result.cause());
        evtHandler.fail(someIntegerCode, result.cause()); // reply with failure related info
      }

    });
  });
```